# Web app on IIS won't attempt to run an external API

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let me explain what we are doing. We have an API which does multiple things for our web applications. One of the calls is to update data and to do that we need to call an external API. As a test bed we are just making sure that the external API gets called in a web app. This works locally but as soon as I put this on IIS it stops working. Can somebody please point me in the right direction as the routine that calls the external API will also be in an API itself and the API will be on IIS.

The following is how we are calling the external API:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Obviously the request is built up of headers and content as we are giving it information such as URL and other things needed for this specific call, again if we run this locally all is fine and even if we have sent it the wrong information we at least can see that it attempted the call. Once the app with the reference of this code (as it is in its own class, in another project so a dll) is on IIS it does not even attempt to call the API.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Creating a new HttpClient for each request is incorrect.  You should create one and reuse it.

Comment: Not sure why you think I am creating a client for each request, i am only creating one and then using it to call the api

Comment: Because your example show `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` if that's just an example, their fair enough.  I thought it was a real code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The API can be used normally in the local environment, but cannot be called in the IIS environment. If an error is not reported when calling the API, but the API does not respond, you can try to configure it in web.config:

```
<system.webserver>

<vailDATION VAIFDAINTEINTEGRATEMODECONFIGUTION = "FALSE" /> /> />

<modules runallManagerModulesforlaterequest = "true" />

...

<add name = "extensionleshandler-integrated-4.0" path = "*" verb = "*" ... />

</System.webserver>
```

In addition, because your API can update the data at the same time, it is not safe to update and delete it by default, because it is not safe. Imagine the user can delete or update the data, but it is not reasonable to request all data to delete or update all the data of the server at a time. However, you can receive the request of the update deletion through a simple configuration, as shown below:

```
<system.webServer> 
<!--The following configuration is to enable IIS7+ to support the Put/Delete method--> 
<httpProtocol> 
<customHeaders> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" /> 
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" /> 
</ customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol> 
<!--This configuration must be added on IIS7/7.5, otherwise an access error will be reported--> 
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
<remove name="WebDAVModule" /> 
</modules> 
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration= "false" /> 
<handlers> 
<remove name="WebDAV" /> 
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" /> 
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /> 
<remove name=" ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /> 
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" /> 
< add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" modules="IsapiModule " scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" /> 
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 " path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition=" integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /> 
</handlers>

<!--Increase the upper limit of GET URL length limit--> <security> 
<requestFiltering> <requestLimits maxUrl="409600" maxQueryString="204800" /> 
</requestFiltering> </security>

</system.webServer>
```

Of course, the API cannot be called in the IIS environment. It may be due to the problem of IIS account permissions. You can re -enter the Administrator account password in IIS to restart the application solution.

If the above method still does not work, please let me know

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, all we are trying to do is call an external api, but our web app which calls said api only works with iis express once we use iis server on the same machine it fails to call

Comment: @altaaf.hussein Can you successfully call other interfaces in the same environment?

Comment: yes, actually we have found an issue. I think its to do with the await. We have noticed that await hangs on IIS and we are thinking maybe it is to do with thread limits. I am however not sure how to go about soling this. Would changing application pools work?

Comment: If so, it may indeed be related to the thread limit of IIS. You can try increasing the maximum number of processes settings in the IIS application pool